# Authorization code is undefined i msal-react v3

Tags: reactjs, oauth, msal-react

So , I have a requirement , where I've to send authorization code to the Backend inorder to get refresh and access token of the microsoft user. I'm using @azure/msal-react library which  handles the popups and redirects , and get the access tokens and other credentials right. However , it returns the code to be undefined. Is there a way to fetch the authorization code using the same library ? . I'm including code for the following

```
const handleMicrosoftLogin = async () => {
    const loginRequest = {
      scopes: ['user.read', 'offline_access']
      // Add the necessary scopes
    }

    try {
      const res = await instance.acquireTokenPopup(loginRequest)
      console.log(res)
      // const user: MsJWTPayload = jwtDecode(res.idToken)

      // setCurrentMailbox({
      //   accessToken: res.accessToken,
      //   name: user?.name || '',
      //   email: user?.preferred_username || ''
      // })
      // setShowPasswordInput(true)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Login failed:', error)
    }
  }
```

here's my instance

```
export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
  auth: {
    clientId: import.meta.env.VITE_MICROSOFT_AUTH_CLIENT_ID,
    authority:
      'https://login.microsoftonline.com/679a768c-6cda-4071-ae37-5de31aeb7629',
    redirectUri: window.location.href
  }
}

export const pca = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig)
```

and here's the response I'm getting

```
{
    "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/",
    "uniqueId": "00000000-0000-0000-831a-ed4248869963",
    "tenantId": "9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad",
    "scopes": [
        "User.Read",
        "openid",
        "profile"
    ],
    "code": undefined,
    "idToken": "abcdefXXXXX",
    "accessToken": "XXXXXX-----",
 ...rest of ms auth data
}
```

Comment: Is that response has idtoken,accesstoken?

Comment: yes it has both access token as well as idtoken

Comment: Then why do you need the code value? I believe your pool's response_type might be 'token'. The code value is valid for one-time use.  If you already have a token in the response, you may use that. I am not currently working with this type of package, but I'm sharing general details here.

Comment: I need to get refresh token , and in msal docs , you can only use auth code to get that.

Comment: We are getting that code value from callbackurl query parameter. Using that Fetching all token through API call. haven't use any library. Following api endpoind used to for fetch token https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID/oauth2/token

Comment: I see, if that's the way , I'll check that as well and let you know. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Im also need this. To show loginPopup, and then to get just the authCode nothing more. Preferably to stay on the same page without redirecting.